# converting start date to datetime as beginning of the day and end date to end of the day

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, time

```
Store PROCEDURE 

--para--
    @StartingDate   DateTime = NULL,
    @EndingDate     DateTime = NULL

--condition --

    dbo.callentry.CallDateTime BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartingDate,
dbo.callentry.CallDateTime) and ISNULL(@EndingDate,dbo.callentry.CallDateTime)
```

Question :

when i pass date `'2012-09-17'` from date picker as para `@StartingDate,` and the same as ending date . it is comparing `2012-09-17 00:00:00.000 to 2012-09-17 00:00:00.000` - will return no records

what i want is records in whole day 2012-09-17

Comment: Use the full Date**Time** - i.e., '2012-09-17 00:00:00` and `2012-09-17 23:59:59`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dbo.callentry.CallDateTime >=ISNULL(@StartingDate,
dbo.callentry.CallDateTime) and dbo.callentry.CallDateTime <=ISNULL(@EndingDate,dbo.callentry.CallDateTime)
```

Also make sure dbo.callentry.CallDateTime this column datatype is also datetime

OR

Also reading from your question. I think when strt and end date are same you just need all the records for that day. if start and end date are same why cant you just use like below:

```
convert(date,dbo.callentry.CallDateTime) =convert(date,ISNULL(@StartingDate,
    dbo.callentry.CallDateTime))
```

In case of sql server 2008 if below just convert both the sides to just date format annd compare

Comment: "convert both the sides to just date format annd compare" - worked ! thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `@StartingDate-1` then?

Or even `DATEADD(d,-1,@StartingDate)`

Or `@EndDate + 1`

Or even `DATEADD(d,1,@EndDate)`

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

> Returns a specified date with the specified number interval (signed
>   integer) added to a specified datepart of that date.

Comment: inthis case wont it return 2 days data?

Comment: It won't return 2 day's data; it will return a full day's data plus any records with a date of the day after and a time of midnight. To ignore those, you could restructure to use two separate WHERE clauses instead of a BETWEEN: `AND dbo.callentry.CallDateTime <=ISNULL(DATEADD(d,1,@EndDate),dbo.callentry.CallDateTime)`